# Number of distinct terms in the expansion of $(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i)^n$ where n,m are positive integers

Tags: solution-verification, permutations

First, I need to establish by induction on *n* that a general term in the expansion will be of the form:
$$\prod_{j=1}^m x_j^{i_j}$$ where $i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_m$ are non-negative integers with the property:
$$\sum_{k=1}^m i_k=n$$.
For *n*=2, the result can be verified easily. For *n*=h, let the statement be true.
For n=h+1, each general term of expansion for n=h will be,
$$\prod_{j=1}^m x_j^{i_j}$$ with $$\sum_{k=1}^m i_k=h$$.
As a result the general term of expansion for n=h+1 is,
$$(\prod_{j=1}^m x_j^{i_j})x_j$$ for some j such that
$$(\sum_{k=1}^m i_k)+1=h+1$$
This concludes the first part of proof.
The number of distinct terms in the expansion can be found by finding all possible vector-valued solutions $$(i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_m)$$ of the equation
$$\sum_{k=1}^m i_k=n$$. This is nothing but $$ n+m-1 \choose m-1$$.
I guess I messed up in the induction part. Please let me know the faults and drawbacks of the proof.

Comment: Everything here is correct, but a lot of the justification is a bit shaky. You kinda just say, this is true, because the general form of the term is like this (where "this" refers to a corollary of what you are trying to prove).